# Python code not rotating and scaling image in affine transformations as expected

Tags: python, math, artificial-intelligence, image-rotation, affinetransform

## Problem:

I am trying to rotate and scale an image using the following Python code:

```py
    """
        img = matplotlib.pyplot.imread('letterR.jpg')
        T = np.array([[0, 2, 0],
             [-2, 0, 0]
             [0, 0, 1]])
    """

img_transformed = np.empty((2000, 2000, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, row in enumerate(img):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        pixel_data = img[i, j, :]
        input_coords = np.array([i, j, 1])
        i_out, j_out, _ = T @ input_coords
        img_transformed[i_out, j_out, :] = pixel_data

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.imshow(img_transformed)
```

[letterR.jpg](https://github.com/amcquistan/affine-image-transforms-python/blob/master/letterR.jpg)

However, when I execute this code, I am not getting the same output as shown in the following image:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wur5m.png)

Instead, I am getting the following output:

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FcH6.png)

## Error messages:

I am not receiving any error messages.

## Additional information:

I have tried executing the code on different machines and I am getting the same results.

I am not sure why the code is not producing the expected output. I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Thank you.

Comment: There are image libraries that perform these types of operations very well that use numpy behind the scenes to do that. Are you certain you want to use numpy directly or are you open to ysing something different?

Comment: But for now, I want to figure what's wrong inside my code.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)? (or, if you didn't know that existed, that rotates a numpy shape. No need for loops).